# break and continue in same foreachloop

Tags: php

is it possible to have 2 conditions in the same foreach loop with one which continues, and one which breaks. so I want to find all full input fields and make them `$$key`, but make only the first empty input field `$_POST['email']`. can I do this in the same loop or do I nee 2 loops?
here is an example, this doesn't work, it breaks.

```
foreach( $_POST as $key=> $for ) {
    if ( $for!='') {
        $$key = $for;   continue;
    } else if ( $for=='') { 
        $$key = $_POST['email'];  break;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Just try it.

Comment: in this example it breaks

Comment: What do you mean 'it breaks'? Can you post details of the error?

Comment: what about using `if ( empty($for) )`?   i couldnt see `...== ''` being an error, but worth a try

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "make only the first empty input field $_POST['email']" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code doesn't make a lot of sense: `if ($for!='')`, then the only other thing which can possibly be is `$for==''`, therefore the second if clause is redundant. Further, what are you tring to achive by setting the result in `$$key` - there may be a reason for this but it is not shown in the code you've published.

Yes, it's quite possible to have multiple break and continue constructs inside a loop. And they will work properly.

However it would be much more efficient to implement your code as simply:

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
```

(although this also removes a lot side-effects and potential vulnerabilities from the code).

Comment: yes, its to do with the key value being the same as the variable name echoed in box.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you obviously can.

```
foreach( $_POST as $key=> $for ) {
    if ( $for != '') {
        $$key = $for; 
    } else { 
        $$key = $_POST['email'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: $$key = $for does not continue after it finds one full box it breaks.

Comment: @user1559811, what? "full box"? what does it even mean?

Comment: @user1559811, I'm not going to change the original code because the OP **might** meant that. I've improved only the parts that were obviously redundant.